# How to run code when app is closed (force kill only)

Tags: java, android

In my application i want the client to send a message to the server when the application is closed, but not when its sent to the background.

onPause() is not a good solution for me, because that means that when the activity goes to the background the code will execute.

I have tried onDestroy but it seems to do nothing at all.

The relevant code:

```
public class ChatActivity extends Activity implements IMessageListener{

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    data.getMsger().sendMsgLogout();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

the code 'data.getMsger().sendMsgLogout();' simply tries to send a message via a socket, but fails to do so on the OnDestroy() event.

Thank you.

Comment: If your app is forcibly closed, it's not going to have time to do anything, and it can't do anything until the user runs it again.

Comment: Put yourself in the shoes of the user. You tell the app to close RIGHT NOW. How would you feel if it then decided to not close right away and do some other stuff instead? What you want is not possible

Comment: you will have to keep a service running in the background. The service provides a onTaskRemoved() method which is executed before the app is removed from the recents screen (by which i guess the app is forcibly closed). Write the code which you want to execute in this method.

Comment: @Shaan_B That only works if the Service is currently running. And you still have to deal with the app being killed from task manager or settings > apps.